# Laravel migration "Cannot add foreign key constraint" error with MySQL database

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-migrations

I am developing a Laravel application. I am using MySQL for the database.  I have created a model class and am trying to run the migration on it. But when, I run migration, I am getting error with adding the foreign key constraint. This is what I have done so far.

First I have migrated the built in Laravel user model running this command.

```
php artisan migrate
```

The users table was created in the database.

Then I created another model running this command.

```
php artisan make:model TodoItem -m
```

Then I added the following code to the migration file.

```
class CreateTodoItemsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('todo_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->text('about');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('todo_items');
    }
}
```

AS you can see above, I am building the relationship between users table and todo_items table by adding a foreign key to the todo_items table. Then, I tried to migrate the TodoItem model by running this command.

```
php artisan migrate
```

When I run the command, I got this error.

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `todo_items` add constraint `todo_items_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

  at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

 Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint")
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

I did the same in my previous project which is using Postgresql. I was working fine. For this project, I am using MySQL database and now it is giving me the above error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because you added `$table->integer('user_id');` to your migration file. You must add an `unsignedInteger` instead of an `integer`, because the original `id` column of the `users` table is `unsigned` (and both columns must be exactly the same).

[EDIT]

Since Laravel 5.8, the `id` column type of the default `users` table is no longer  an `integer`. It is now a `bigInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable()->index();  
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: Please add always some explanation to the code to improve your answer and to give more information to future users

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$table->integer('user_id');
```

To this

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running it like this, this should work.

// also, do the unsigned thing the people above me posted

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('todo_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->text('about');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
    Schema::table('todo_items', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('CASCADE')->onDelete('CASCADE');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that either mysql didn't want foreign keys during table creation, or laravel was issuing them in the wrong order.

In short, this didn't work:

```
Schema::create('todo_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->text('about');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

This worked:

> ```
>   Schema::create('todo_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
>     $table->text('about');
>     $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
>     $table->increments('id');
>     $table->timestamps();
> ```
>
> });
>
> ```
> Schema::table('todo_items',  function(Blueprint $table){
>
>     $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
> });
> ```